# How does Ruby define base methods such as `if` and `unless`?

Tags: ruby, if-statement, syntax, conditional-statements

I've been curious about how the Ruby language defines base methods such as `if` and `unless`. I've also cloned the [Ruby source code](https://github.com/ruby/ruby) repository and tried to search around, but didn't really understand how they wrote it.

Comment: those are not methods.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Thanks for your reply, can I have a little suggest about what it is, and how can I investigate more to it?

Comment: They are keywords. `if` expression, for example, is implemented/described like this: https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/f380a255200aaa5c5838e7bef5ed19a7569b8c12/parse.y#L3363-L3378. You can't define new keywords or syntactical constructs in user code.

Comment: **This is a good question** that doesn't deserve the close votes it's attracting because newcomers to Ruby are often told that "everything is an object" or "everything is an expression." Understanding how to identify Ruby's keywords and the various parts of its custom interpreter are not easily searched unless you already know part of the answer.

Answer (score 3):

> I've been curious about how can the Ruby language define their base method such as If / Unless.

Unlike many other programming languages, Ruby does not have a single formal specification that defines what certain language constructs mean.

There are several resources, the *sum* of which can be considered kind of a specification for the Ruby programming language.

Some of these resources are:

- The [ISO/IEC 30170:2012 *Information technology — Programming languages — Ruby* specification](https://iso.org/standard/59579.html) – Note that the ISO Ruby Specification was written around 2009–2010 with the specific goal that all existing Ruby implementations at the time would easily be compliant. Since YARV only implements Ruby 1.9+ and MRI only implements Ruby 1.8 and lower, this means that the ISO Ruby Specification only contains features that are common to both Ruby 1.8 and Ruby 1.9. Also, the ISO Ruby Specification was specifically intended to be minimal and only contain the features that are absolutely required for writing Ruby programs. Because of that, it does for example only specify `String`s very broadly (since they have changed significantly between Ruby 1.8 and Ruby 1.9). It obviously also does not specify features which were added after the ISO Ruby Specification was written, such as Ractors.
- [The Ruby Spec Suite aka `ruby/spec`](https://github.com/ruby/spec/) – Note that the `ruby/spec` is unfortunately far from complete. However, I quite like it because it is written in Ruby instead of "ISO-standardese", which is much easier to read for a Rubyist, and it doubles as an executable conformance test suite.
- [*The Ruby Programming Language* by David Flanagan and Yukihiro 'matz' Matsumoto](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596516177) – This book was written by David Flanagan together with Ruby's creator matz to serve as a Language Reference for Ruby.
- [*Programming Ruby* by Dave Thomas, Andy Hunt, and Chad Fowler](https://pragprog.com/titles/ruby4/programming-ruby-1-9-2-0-4th-edition/) – This book was the first English book about Ruby and served as *the* standard introduction and description of Ruby for a long time. This book also first documented the Ruby core library and standard library, and the authors donated that documentation back to the community.
- The [Ruby Issue Tracking System](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/), specifically, the [*Feature* sub-tracker](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/projects/ruby-master/issues?tracker_id=2) – However, please note that unfortunately, the community is really, really bad at distinguishing between Tickets about the Ruby Programming Language and Tickets about the YARV Ruby Implementation: they both get intermingled in the tracker.
- The Meeting Logs of the [Ruby Developer Meetings](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/14770).
- New features are often discussed on the [mailing lists](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/community/mailing-lists/), in particular the [ruby-core (English)](http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/ruby/ruby-core/index.shtml) and [ruby-dev (Japanese)](http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/ruby/ruby-dev/index.shtml) mailing lists.
- The [Ruby documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/) – Again, be aware that this documentation is generated from the source code of YARV and does not distinguish between features of Ruby and features of YARV.
- In the past, there were a couple of attempts of formalizing changes to the Ruby Specification, such as the [Ruby Change Request (RCR)](http://rcrchive.net/) and [Ruby Enhancement Proposal (REP)](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/projects/ruby/wiki/Ruby_Enhancement_Proposals) processes, both of which were unsuccessful.
- If all else fails, you need to check the source code of the popular Ruby implementations to see what they *actually* do.

The *`if` conditional expression* is specified in section 11.5.2.2.2 *The `if` expression* of the ISO/IEC 30170:2012 *Information technology — Programming languages — Ruby* specification like this:

> ## 11.5.2.2.2 *The `if` expression*
>
> ### Syntax
>
> - *if-expression* ::
>
>   - `if` *expression* *then-clause* *elsif-clause*<sup>*****</sup> *else-clause*<sup>**?**</sup> `end`
> - *then-clause* ::
>
>   - *separator* *compound-statement*
>     **|** *separator*<sup>**?**</sup> `then` *compound-statement*
> - *else-clause* ::
>
>   - `else` *compound-statement*
> - *elsif-clause* ::
>
>   - `elsif` *expression* *then-clause*
>
> ## Semantics
>
> The *if-expression* is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Evaluate *expression*. Let **V** be the resulting value.
> 2. If **V** is a trueish object, evaluate the *compound-statement* of the *then-clause*. The value of the *if-expression* is the resulting value. In this case, *elsif-clause*s and the *else-clause*, if any, are not evaluated.
> 3. If **V** is a falseish object, and if there is no *elsif-clause* and no *else-clause*, then the value of the *if-expression* is `nil`.
> 4. If **V** is a falseish object, and if there is no *elsif-clause* but there is an *else-clause*, then evaluate the *compound-statement* of the *else-clause*. The value of the *if-expression* is the resulting value.
> 5. If **V** is a falseish object, and if there are one or more *elsif-clause*s, evaluate the sequence of *elsif-clause*s as follows:
>
>    1. Evaluate the *expression* of each *elsif-clause* in the order they appear in the program text, until there is an *elsif-clause* for which *expression* evaluates to a trueish object.
>       Let **T** be this *elsif-clause*.
>    2. If **T** exists, evaluate the *compound-statement* of its *then-clause*. The value of the *if-expression* is the resulting value. Other
>       *elsif-clause*s and an *else-clause* following **T**, if any, are not evaluated.
>    3. If **T** does not exist, and if there is an *else-clause*, then evaluate the *compound-statement* of the *else-clause*. The value of the *if-expression* is the resulting value.
>    4. If **T** does not exist, and if there is no *else-clause*, then the value of the *if-expression* is `nil`.

This is of course pretty much how you expect a conditional expression to work. `unless` is defined in the next section, but there are no surprises there.

A less formal specification is given in [`language/if_spec.rb`](https://github.com/ruby/spec/blob/master/language/if_spec.rb#L3-L309) of the `ruby/spec`.

If you would rather like to know how the conditional expression is *implemented* than how it is *defined*, the first question you have to ask yourself is: implemented *where*? I.e. which Ruby implementation are you interested in?

Personally, I always prefer to look at [Rubinius](https://rubinius.com/), even though it is unfortunately no longer actively maintained. You can find the implementation of the *`if` conditional expression* in the [`rubinius-code`](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius-code/) subproject in  [`lib/rubinius/code/ast/control_flow.rb`](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius-code/blob/master/lib/rubinius/code/ast/control_flow.rb#L306-L346), and it looks something like this (slightly abridged for clarity):

```ruby
done = g.new_label
else_label = g.new_label

@condition.bytecode(g)
g.goto_if_false else_label

@body.bytecode(g)
g.goto done

else_label.set!
@else.bytecode(g)

done.set!
```

Again, it looks pretty much like you would expect from a Smalltalk-80 style stack-based byte code VM: we define two labels, one (`done`) is at the end of the block, the other (`else_label`) in the middle. We splice the byte code of the condition into the generated byte code and execute a `GOTO` to the `else_label` if the top of the stack is falsey, thus skipping over the byte code of the body, which we splice in after the `GOTO` and before the `else_label`. After the byte code of the body, we execute a `GOTO` to the `done` label and splice in the byte code of the `else` branch after the `else_label` label and before the `done` label.

You might notice that there is no mention of `elsif` here nor of the possibility that the `else` might be missing. This is handled by a transformation pass which transforms an `if` without `else` into an `if` with an empty `else` and an `if` with `elsif` into a series of `if` with `else` and nested `if`.

As an interesting counterpoint to Rubinius, I also like to check out [TruffleRuby](https://graalvm.org/ruby/). Here is what the implementation looks like in [`src/main/java/org/truffleruby/language/control/IfElseNode.java`](https://github.com/oracle/truffleruby/blob/master/src/main/java/org/truffleruby/language/control/IfElseNode.java#L28-L47):

```java
public IfElseNode(RubyNode condition, RubyNode thenBody, RubyNode elseBody) {
    this.condition = BooleanCastNodeGen.create(condition);
    this.thenBody = thenBody;
    this.elseBody = elseBody;
}

@Override
public Object execute(VirtualFrame frame) {
    if (conditionProfile.profile(condition.executeBoolean(frame))) {
        return thenBody.execute(frame);
    } else {
        return elseBody.execute(frame);
    }
}
```

Again, this is pretty much what you would expect from a simple AST-walking interpreter. Now, of course, [Truffle](https://graalvm.org/graalvm-as-a-platform/language-implementation-framework/) is anything *but* a "simple AST-walking interpreter", but the amazing thing about the Truffle Language Implementation Framework is that you write your language implementation *as-if* you were writing a simple AST-walking interpreter and Truffle will automatically generate a high-performance compiler for you.

(If you are familiar with the [RPython Language Implementation Framework](https://rpython.readthedocs.io/), then you will note some similarities: in RPython, you also write a simple interpreter, in this case, a simple byte code interpreter loop, and RPython automatically generates a JIT compiler for you. There used to be a Ruby implementation on RPython called [Topaz](https://github.com/topazproject/topaz), but it is no longer under active development.)

The last Ruby implementation I want to look at is [Opal](https://opalrb.com/). Its implementation of the *`if` conditional expression* is in [`lib/opal/nodes/if.rb`](https://github.com/opal/opal/blob/master/lib/opal/nodes/if.rb#L26-L67). There are some nifty optimizations that it tries to do but if you remove all of the optimizations, then you can essentially see that in the most general case, the Ruby snippet

```ruby
if condition
  then_body
else
  else_body
end
```

is compiled to the ECMAScript snippet

```js
(
    await(
        async function () {
            if (/* compiled version of `condition` */) {
                return /* compiled version of `then_branch` */;
            } else {
                return /* compiled version of `else_branch` */;
            }
            return nil;
        }()
    )
)
```

There are some other Ruby implementations you could look at as well, but I find Rubinius, Opal, and TruffleRuby the most readable (in that order).

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR

`if` and `unless` are Ruby keywords, not objects. Below, I provide links to Ruby's keyword and syntax documentation, as well as links to the actual keyword token definitions within the Ruby source code.

### Ruby Keywords

While *most* things in Ruby are objects or expressions, there are some things that are simply language keywords. The `if` and `unless` keywords are two of them.

While you can certainly find them in the source, for more practical purposes you can find them in the Ruby [keywords documentation](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.1/doc/keywords_rdoc.html) or [syntax documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.1/doc/syntax_rdoc.html) generated for each released version.

### Links Related to Ruby's Interpreter and Defined Tokens

You may also want to look at Ruby's [Ripper module](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.1.1/libdoc/ripper/rdoc/Ripper.html) for additional references to Ruby's custom tokenizer, parser, and lexer if you're looking for more information about how the interpreter works. You can also look at [parse.y](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/master/parse.y) for the actual list of tokens used by the parser. Specifically, the tokens for the conditionals you're asking about are currently located at:

- [keyword_if](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/master/parse.y#L1148=)
- [keyword_unless](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/master/parse.y#L1149=)